# How do I make git config --global alias. as alias

Tags: git

I was actually trying to create a git alias for `git config --global alias` command but couldn't succeed.

[I tried the one shown in the image but it didn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNrvM.png)

E.g. I tried something like below:

```
$ git config --global alias.als 'config --global alias'
$ git als.s status
git: 'als.s' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
        alias
```

Comment: From the [doc](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-alias), "To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing Git commands are ignored."

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that Git interprets `als.s` as a single command, and only treats names with a period differently for certain commands to access the given property. This is the case for `config` and `alias`, but not for aliases themselves.

In general, only alphanumeric characters and `-` are allowed, see the [Git documentation on git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_configuration_file):

> The variable names are case-insensitive, allow only alphanumeric characters and `-`, and must start with an alphabetic character.

For the same reason, creating native Bash or ZSH aliases this way would not work either.

However, you can create a function to do this.

```bash
als() {
    git config --global alias."$1" "$2"
}
```

And use it like this:

```bash
$ als s status
```

Assuming you are using Bash or ZSH, you can add the function to your config file, and source the file with `source <config-file>` to apply the change. After that you can use the command as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

As @dbran points out the alias recognition works by just subbing in a replacement token list, there's no token pasting or splitting built in. You *can* invoke the shell to do any needed heavier lifting, though:

```
git config --global alias.als '!f() { git config --global alias."$@"; }; f'
```

`!` is the traditional shell-escape marker, feed what follows to the shell; `name() { ; };` defines `name` as a shell function, `"$@"` subs in all the current arguments, once a shell function is defined it becomes a shell command that runs inline.

Then `git als s status` works.